# obtener el valor de una función booleana javascript en php

Tags: php, javascript, html

buenas tengo una duda verán tengo una función javascript que tendría que retornar una variable booleana pero quiero recibirla en php, esta es mi función.

```
  function validar(){
       var verificado = true;
        var copia = document.getElementById("txtcopia").value;
        var captcha = document.getElementById("captcha").value;

        if(copia == captcha){
            verificado=true;
            alert("es correcto el captcha");

             return verificado;



        }else{
            verificado=false;
            alert("El codigo Ingresado no coincide");
            return verificado;

        }

    }
```

y quiero recibirla para trabajar de esta forma

```
$_valor=validar();
if(!$_valor){
echo "vuelve a ingresar captcha.";
        formRegistro();


}

else{
echo "procederemos a guardar tus datos";
}
```

algun consejo ?

Comment: Donde esta la parte donde envias tu dato a php??, la pregunta no es sobre como enviar informacion a otra parte, si no sobre como obtener el valor de una funcion. Si tu duda es mas bien como transportar cierta informacion a PHP, entonces deberas editar el titulo de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes mezclar así javascript con PHP. 
Javascript se ejecuta al lado del cliente, y PHP se ejecuta al lado del servidor, por lo tanto, no son correspondientes ni las peticiones ni los resultados. 
Para ese caso sugiero que uses AJAX (Mejor con JQuery).

Answer (score -2):

Te recomiendo utilizar valores enteros como 1 y 0 en lugar de retornar un booleano.

```
$_valor=validar();
if($_valor == 0){
  echo "vuelve a ingresar captcha.";
  formRegistro();
}
else{
  echo "procederemos a guardar tus datos";
}
```

Es importante tener cuidado cuando trabajamos con booleano, por ejemplo cuando trabajamos con funciones en la BD y se devuelva "true" o "false" resulta que en algunas versiones devuelve "t" (true) o "f" (false), por consecuente tenemos ese inconveniente en php o cualquier lenguaje que estemos utilizando.

Comment: Te saldrá error, porque no encontrará la función validar(). Esa función en JAVASCRIPT es inalcanzable por PHP.
Javascript se ejecuta al lado del cliente, y PHP se ejecuta al lado del servidor...

Comment: Totalmene de acuerdo con Erik.